# how to check if date is invalid Boost C++

Tags: c++, date, boost

Hi all im trying to use a function to check if my date is a valid date.

```
std::string dateString = "2015," + contentMonth + "," + contentDay;
date d(from_string(dateString));
if(d.is_not_a_date()) //this is not working... why?
return true;
else
return false;
```

but i get an error when it passes through d.is_not_a_date().
is there an error in the code?

Comment: What is in `dateString`? What is the result of `from_string()`? What is the error?

Comment: lets say if i key in a wrong month and day,
dateString will be "2015,marche,100"

from string will create a date out of the string.

its a runtime error.

Comment: What does `from_string()` do with an invalid date?

Comment: There's a good tutorial on date parsing with boost here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure it comes from `is_not_a_date`? Or is `from_string` throwing an exception due to the invalid date?

Comment: hmmm yes sorry i think from string is throwing an exception due to the ivalid date. is there any other way that i can check if my date is a valid or invalid input?

Comment: @zacaxe: Catch the exception, I guess.